# Php mysql fetch array result in html

Tags: php, mysql

i am using the below code using to display the mysql data. The problem is while displaying the data in HTML, the data is showing in a single line and not getting wrapped.

```
<?php 
//while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$res['topic']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['issue']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['solution']."</td>";
    echo "<td><div align='center'><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";       
}
?>
```

Please help me with the code.

Comment: what is the out put you get add some css to td & tr

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to close the `<tr>` tag, so, all your data are in the same row.

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$res['topic']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['issue']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['solution']."</td>";
    echo "<td><div align='center'><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";  
    echo "</tr>"; // << close <tr> tag     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` where you want to break the line.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to print `<table>` to create table

```
echo "<table>";
.
.
.
.
echo "</table>";
```

```html
without table tag<br>
<tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
with table taaag
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Demo,For demo use the array instead of table data,

```
<?php
$data=array(array("id"=>1,"topic"=>"php","issue"=>"var 
error","solution"=>"declare 
first"),array("id"=>2,"topic"=>"asp","issue"=>"var error 
validatipn","solution"=>"validate js add")); 
?>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>topic</th><th>issue</th><th>solution</th><th>Action</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
 foreach($data as $res)
 { 
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$res['topic']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$res['issue']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$res['solution']."</td>";
 echo "<td><div align='center'><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | 
 <a 
href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you 
want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td></tr>";       
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Dear Dweb still i ma facing the same issue.  the data in the html is displayign in a single lengthy line and its not coming in second line

Comment: I have changed the code see above,for demostration i have used the array value instead of table data..

Comment: No sir, still the same issue

Comment: @ Dweb could you please help me with the above code

Comment: can you provide complete code upto fetching data from database??

Comment: Please provide me your email id so that i can send